# Fetch data from Network

Tags: android, flutter, http, dart, cross-platform

I want  to  fetch data from internet and display in my flutter app and I did that using http and works fine also , but when I exit from debug and installed same apk  in android  which I build using `flutter build apk` then Its not working means cant fetch data

In my project I have created an apk which shows apps killed by google,
the Circular Progress Indicator will be Displayed until I fetch data from website.
After fetching data It will Displayed in cards on my app .

but it works fine only in debug mode .
after installing on android it shows only Circular Progress Indicator and title of app in appBar

help me to resolve this I'm new flutter user

Comment: what error are you seeing in logs?

Comment: It running well in debug mode so there is no errors in logs

Comment: this is happening only for http and not https ?

Comment: i have added app icon from network that also not showing

Comment: @AndroidGuy no i am not using https now using only package:http/http.dart

Comment: what do you mean by app icon from the network? the icon which is shown in mobile device for an app ?

Comment: when we use appBar in scaffold() I am talking about  leading:Icon

Comment: because you're missing the internet permission over your Android manifest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following in your AndroidManifest.xml, if you are using http

```
android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
```

Comment: I got new error   **
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugMainManifest'.
> com.android.manifmerger.ManifestMerger2$MergeFailureException: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 6; columnNumber: 31; Element type "android:usesCleartextTraffic" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>".

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

**   so i removed that line again and LOL itz working now :D  dont know how..

Comment: Can you share the exact xml file, you are missing something syntactic

Comment: Yes but Now its resolved don't know how but my first two projects not working but this time it auto resolved itself but dont know what i did ;D